# Android: hiding a textview in a widget depending on it's content

Tags: android, widget, textview, hide

I'm relatively new to Android and trying to switch off a range of textviews in my widget class depending on their content.

The textview text is set by a configuration class when the widget is initially placed and I want empty fields to be deleted from the layout upon loading.

The code from my widget class is below, but for some reason the code contained within the IF statements does not run.

Any suggestions?

My gut feeling is that the widget content is being drawn BEFORE the if statements are executed, but I'm not sure how I would alter this as the textviews need to be initialized before they can be turned off, right?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
// import android.app.PendingIntent;

public class WidgetConfig extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    EditText infocontext;
    EditText infoname;
    EditText infoaddress1;
    EditText infoaddress2;
    EditText infoaddress3;
    EditText infoaddress4;
    EditText infophone;
    EditText infoemail;
    AppWidgetManager awm;
    Context c;
    int awID;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.widgetconfig);
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bwidgetconfig);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        c = WidgetConfig.this;
        infocontext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etcontext);
        infoname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etname);
        infoaddress1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etaddress1);
        infoaddress2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etaddress2);
        infoaddress3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etaddress3);
        infoaddress4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etaddress4);
        infophone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etphone);
        infoemail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etemail);
        //Getting info about the widget that launched this Activity
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        if (extras !=null){
            awID = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID
            );

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String str_context = infocontext.getText().toString();
        String str_name = infoname.getText().toString();
        String str_address1 = infoaddress1.getText().toString();
        String str_address2 = infoaddress2.getText().toString();
        String str_address3 = infoaddress3.getText().toString();
        String str_address4 = infoaddress4.getText().toString();
        String str_phone = infophone.getText().toString();
        String str_email = infoemail.getText().toString();

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

        awm.updateAppWidget(awID, views);

        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.tvName, View.GONE);
        if (str_name != null){
            views.setViewVisibility(R.id.tvName, View.VISIBLE);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvName, str_name);
        }

        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.tvAddress1, View.GONE);
        if (str_address1 != null){
            views.setViewVisibility(R.id.tvAddress1, View.VISIBLE);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvAddress1, str_address1);
        }

        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.tvAddress2, View.GONE);
        if (str_address2 != null){
            views.setViewVisibility(R.id.tvAddress2, View.VISIBLE);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvAddress2, str_address2);
        }

        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.tvAddress3, View.GONE);
        if (str_address3 != null){
            views.setViewVisibility(R.id.tvAddress3, View.VISIBLE);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvAddress3, str_address3);
        }     

        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.tvAddress4, View.GONE);
        if (str_address4 != null){
            views.setViewVisibility(R.id.tvAddress4, View.VISIBLE);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvAddress4, str_address4);
        }  

        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.tvPhone, View.GONE);
        if (str_phone != null){
            views.setViewVisibility(R.id.tvPhone, View.VISIBLE);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPhone, str_phone);
        } 

        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.tvEmail, View.GONE);
        if (str_email != null){
            views.setViewVisibility(R.id.tvEmail, View.VISIBLE);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvEmail, str_email);
        }

        awm.updateAppWidget(awID, views);

        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, awID);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
        finish();

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried logging in your `onClick` function, or stepping through in a debugger?

Comment: That will be the next step tonight when I get home from work. I was hoping someone wiser than me might be able to spot the problem straight away :)